# Configure Firebug to open file in notepad++ at given error line

Tags: notepad++, parameter-passing, firebug

I already defined Notepad++ as the default editor for Firebug. I have also tried several syntax versions to opening the file at a given line number with the option `-n<line number>` as mentioned [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches).

Whatever I try, like `"-n%line %file"` (with and without quotes, with leading %file, with %url) Notepad++ opens the correct file, but never jumps to the given error line.

What do I have to enter as correct Parameter to jump directly to the error line shown in Firebug?

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me using Firefox 45.0.2 + Firebug 2.0.16 on Windows 7 using the following configuration:

[image: External editor configuration for Notepad++]

Though note, [due to a bug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/8010) the sources **are not opened at all** if they are accessed via http://localhost. I've filed a [bug report for that](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/8010).